# Can 'more + [adjective] + [plural noun]' be ambiguous sometimes?

Tags: comparatives

> The government would have to take **more fundamental steps** to address
>   the minority's disquiet.

Is this sentence ambiguous? May the implied meanings include:

1. The government should increase the **number** of such fundamental
   steps.
2. The government should step up the **fundamentality** of
   [future] steps.

Comment: Of course, yes. It could be more steps, or steps that are more fundamental in nature. Sometimes the context resolves the ambiguity, at others a rephrasing may be needed. Politicians do neither, on purpose, though. :)

Comment: @Kris. There's perhaps a comment in your words, but you have given a clear answer. I suggest you post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

The government would have to take more **(suggestion: additional, better, further)** fundamental steps to address the minority's disquiet.